# openGL ES Rotation about a point

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm attempting to get an object to rotate about the origin point (0,0,0)

I'm following some guidelines from this [blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-2-look-at.html) and was able to get the basic rotation about the Z axis and it makes a very tight circle about the Z azis.

When I change it to the X or Y axis the triangle I made goes behind me and then shows up from the other side.

The basic effect I'm hoping to achieve is to have it spin right infront of the camera.

I understand that I would have to rotate it by the amount I want and then translate it back to the origin, but I'm not quite sure on how to figure out how much to translate it by.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction about this especially the formula I would need to use to translate it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to answer without seeing your code, but it sounds like you want to first translate the center of the triangle to the origin, rotate, then translate back to the triangle's original position.  glRotate() rotates around the origin, not an arbitrary point.

So, effectively,

```
glTranslatef(centerX, centerY, centerZ);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(-centerX, -centerY, -centerZ);
```

Remember that OpenGL transformations are applied in reverse order that they are specified in the code, so the above translates by -(centerX, centerY, centerZ), then rotates, then translates back by (centerX, centerY, centerZ).

Check out [Chapter 3 of the OpenGL Programming Guide](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter03.html) for more information.

Comment: I've tried that, the only differences is that all my values were 0, which I thought would be the center, but it seems that [0,0,0] is not my center then?

Comment: By "center", I meant the center of rotation -- where you want the rotation to be centered about.  If you want the rotation to go around one of the triangle's vertices, then use the (x, y, z) values for that vertex as (centerX, centerY, centerZ) values.  If you want the rotation to go around the center of the triangle, then you'll need to compute the point at the center of the triangle and use those values.  The center of a triangle can be computed simply by averaging the vertices together, for example, cx = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3, where x1 is the x-coordinate of the first vertex, etc.